# How to NOT have the first word removed in JS typewriter effect?

Tags: javascript, text

I'm desperately looking for a variation of the typewriter effect below: I'd love to NOT have the first word removed after the first sentence has built up:

Ideally, the first line "My first sentence" builds up, then only "first sentence" gets removed and the first word, "My", STAYS on screen. Then "second sentence" builds up, gets removed, then "third sentence" builds up, gets removed and then "last sentence" builds up and, finally, the whole string "My last sentence" stays on screen. Thank you a million in advance for your support!

PS: Here's the link for easy editing: [codepen.io/stevenkeen/pen/ZqrBWg](http://codepen.io/stevenkeen/pen/ZqrBWg)

```js
// function([string1, string2], target id, [color1,color2], initial pause, final pause)
consoleText(
  [
    "My first sentence",
    "My second sentence",
    "My third sentence",
    "My last sentence"
  ],
  "text",
  ["tomato", "rebeccapurple", "lightblue"],
  5000,
  500000
);

function consoleText(words, id, colors, initialPause, finalPause) {
  if (colors === undefined) colors = ["#fff"];
  var visible = true;
  var con = document.getElementById("console");
  var letterCount = 1;
  var x = 1;
  var initialCount = 0;
  var waiting = false;
  var target = document.getElementById(id);
  var justStarted = true;
  target.setAttribute("style", "color:" + colors[0]);
  window.setInterval(function() {
    if (initialCount < initialPause) {
      initialCount += 120;
    } else if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var usedColor = colors.shift();
        var usedWord = words.shift();
        x = 1;
        target.setAttribute("style", "color:" + colors[0]);
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000);
    } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        x = -1;
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, words.length === 1 ? finalPause : 1000);
    } else if (waiting === false) {
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount);
      letterCount += x;
    }
  }, 120);
  window.setInterval(function() {
    if (visible === true) {
      con.className = "console-underscore hidden";
      visible = false;
    } else {
      con.className = "console-underscore";

      visible = true;
    }
  }, 400);
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:700);
body {
  background: #111;
}
.hidden {
  opacity:0;
}
.console-container {
 
  font-family:Khula;
  font-size:4em;
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  width:600px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
.console-underscore {
   display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:-0.14em;
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='console-container'><span id='text'></span><div class='console-underscore' id='console'>&#95;</div></div>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a working code example that is as minimal as possible? It's a little difficult to make out what you're trying to do, and what could be going wrong, from the example you've provided

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML file for same?

Comment: Hello Ankur and Oliver, thank you so much for your willingness to help! The code can be found right here: https://codepen.io/stevenkeen/pen/ZqrBWg

Comment: There are two ways I can see of doing this; by specifying which words should be deleted, or by checking for differences between each item and then calculating which characters to delete from that. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Hi @Oliver, it would be terrific if I could specify which words should be deleted from each individual item - thank you again for all the help and support!

Comment: My opinion is that it would be better to go with a library for something like this. https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/ seems quite popular

Comment: Hi @OliverRadini, thank you so much for the reply. I've tried typed.js before, but I couldn't get it to work (see https://codepen.io/stevenkeen/pen/NOywLN), so I was very much hoping to find a solution with the JS typewriter effect mentioned above. Would it be easier to make it work if we followed the second approach you suggested above (by checking for differences between each item and then calculating which characters to delete from that)? This way would be perfectly fine for me as well! I'd be so grateful if you would help me get this to work - thank you a million in advance again!

Comment: Here's a code pen
https://codepen.io/frustrated-programmer/pen/GYxKQQ
with a working solution

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE – you are my hero, @Frustrated programmer! You really made my day! This is an incredibly helpful code - thanks so much for everything, I really do appreciate it! Amazing!

Comment: Haha, your code is so incredibly amazing and overwhelming that I cannot even get the script to keep the last text on the screen in the end (and the cursor blinking), @Frustrated programmer. Do you think you could maybe include this behavior in your codepen for me? That would be totally amazing! Also, is there any chance to set the original "delay" at the beginning of the script (in which only the curser blinks before the typewriter effect starts)? THANK YOU SO MUCH AGAIN FOR EVERYTHING!

Comment: check now :D. also be sure next time to give it a go yourself as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Frustrated programmer, it's beautiful and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again for your time and support and have a nice weekend!